# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "a" y "ha"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, preposiciones

¿Pueden explicarme la diferencia entre "a" y "ha"?

No la entiendo y agradecería ayuda al respecto. Estuve buscando una solución en internet pero no he podido encontrar una que lo explique bien y que yo entienda.

Answer (score 5):

La diferencia es mucha porque son dos palabras completamente diferentes aunque se pronuncien igual

Esto es una duda frecuente y encontré esta respuesta [aquí](http://gramaticacomosedice.blogspot.com.co/2014/05/diferencia-entre-a-ha-ah-error-horrible.html)

> -A es una preposición con múltiples acepciones: “Voy **a** ver una película **a** Madrid”, “Esta colonia sabe **a** miel”, “Me encanta montar **a**
>   caballo”, etc.
>
> -Ha se utiliza para formar la tercera persona del singular del pretérito perfecto: “Él **ha** ido a la bolera”, “Mi prima **ha** aprobado
>   todo”, “Jorge **ha** aprendido la lección”, etc.
>
> -Ah es una interjección empleada para denotar pena, admiración o sorpresa: “Ah, que no vienes…”, “¡Ah!, pobre chico”, “¡Ah!, ahora me
>   acuerdo”, etc.

**A** esa respuesta le hace falta aclarar que **ha** viene del verbo **haber**

Aunque tu pregunta la hiciste en español creo que te sirve un paralelo con el inglés así:

> Voy **a** ver una película **a** Madrid = I'll go **to** see a movie **in** Madrid

En este caso la preposición "a" equivale a las preposiciones *to* e *in*

> Jorge ha aprendido la lección = Jorge has learned his lesson.

En este caso es claro que "ha" cumple la misma función que el verbo "have" cumple en inglés.

Comment: Si te es más útil una respuesta completamente en inglés puedes preguntar en inglés.

Comment: Gracias por a ayuda, creo que entiendo ahora. Entonces, se use "a" por conectar las palabras. Por ejemplo, en español: Tenemos que ir **a** España y en Inglés: We need to go **to** Spain. También, se usa "ha" y un otro verbo para decir que está haciendo el verbo, y en Inglés, "ha" es cómo "has".

Answer (score 2):

Como ya te han dicho, con hache forma parte del verbo haber, auxiliar, y sola es la preposición, normalmente indicando dirección.

---

Para aportar algo más, hay un truco bastante sencillo para saber cuándo escribirla con hache y cuándo no:

> Si se puede cambiar por han y la oración sigue teniendo sentido, se
>   escribe con hache.

Un par de ejemplos:

1. *Nos tenemos que ir a la escuela (We have to go to school)*.

Si cambiamos la a por "an", no tiene sentido. No se puede decir *Nos tenemos que ir an la escuela*. Por lo tanto, sin hache.

2. *Ha dicho que tiene que marcharse (He said he has to leave)*.

Esta vez, en cambio, si cambiamos ha por han, la oración sigue siendo válida: *Han dicho que tiene que marcharse (They said he has to leave)*. El sujeto cambia de singular a plural, pero es una oración bien formada.

---

PD: Si necesitas traducción al inglés o no entiendes algo, dime.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Entiendo todo en español, la única cosa es que no recuerdo la diferencia entre unas palabras, como en esta pregunta.

Comment: Este truco es correcto, pero ojo: a veces necesitas cambiar algún otro elemento de la oración al plural para que funcione (p. ej.: *Juan ha venido solo* --> *Juan y Pedro han venido solos*).

Answer (score 1):

Por complementar las otras respuestas, que profundizan en la diferencia entre ambas palabras, os cuento el truco que recuerdo que me enseñaron a mí de pequeño en el colegio:

- Si la palabra que va detrás acaba en *-ado*, *-ido* o *-to*, se escribe **ha**. (Es decir, si lo que va detrás es un verbo en participio, pero por entonces no sabíamos lo que era un participio. Seguramente se pueda encontrar alguna excepción a esta norma, como "me fui a Sagunto", pero por lo general funciona bien si se excluyen los nombres propios.) Ejemplos: *Juan no ha hablado conmigo*. *Pepe se lo ha comido todo*. *María nunca ha roto un plato*.
- Si la palabra que va detrás es la preposición *de*, también se escribe **ha**. Ejemplo: *Tu niño ha de comportarse mejor*.
- En cualquier otro caso, se escribe **a**.

Comment: Pero en tu segunda pregunta, también no se puede decir: Pepe se comí todo. Pero creo que la diferencia es que se usa comí cuando sabes al tiempo exacto que comí y se usa ha comido cuando es màs general. Lo que dije es correcto o no?

Comment: @JimboBaggins la diferencia entre "Pepe se lo ha comido todo" y "Pepe se lo comió todo" daría para otra extensa pregunta. :-)